# How to enable Content Query Web Part on SharePoint Server 2010 Standard?

Tags: content-query-web-part, site-collection

I'm working with a new site collection in SharePoint Server 2010 Standard created using the Blank Site template.  I would like to add a Content Query Web Part to one of my web part pages, however, this web part does not show up any of the web part category lists.  I have already gone into Site Collection Administration → Site Collection Features and activated the Search Server Web Parts, but the CQWP still doesn't show up.  Am I missing something?

Comment: In case anyone else is beating their head against a wall, CQWP is not part of SharePoint Foundation. Please see http://www.sharepointconfig.com/2010/06/sharepoint-2010-web-parts-by-license-type/ for details.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Publishing Features need to be active on the site collection for the web part to appear.  It can be activated from the Site Settings, Site collection features screen.